# Symfony 2 TDD get original data in functional test

Tags: php, symfony, phpunit, functional-testing

So I was watching Adam Wathan and his live TDD Laravel on YT. He did one very interesting thing which resonated with me. When he writes functional tests, he does not assert against returned html (as html can change by front end devs), however Laravel provides this call in test `$this->response->getOriginalContent()->getData()` where you get original data and you can assert against it.

I've tried to get to original response data in test but no success.Is it even possible to get original data in Symfony test? If so, how?

**UPDATE:**

Here is YT link. It starts where he explains the whole idea.
[enter link description here](https://youtu.be/rWzN7mhx3u0?t=858)

Comment: As I understand, in this case it isn't a functional test it's a unit test on the controller returned data.

Comment: What is original content and it's data? What is your assertion? Please rephrase your question in a way where we don't have to watch the video, in case the link will not work in the future, e.g. because the video was removed. You can call `$client->getResponse()` to get the response object and do assertions on that instead of using the crawler. Does that answer your question?

Comment: @COil I would not call it unit test. For me as for Adam its still functional.

Comment: @dbrumann the idea is to test route. But instead of querying html, you test variables that are being passed to template. For example, lets say you have some price variable and front-end dev codes its $59.00, and you create test to find value $59.00 in html. However at some point designer changes the format to $59 and front-end dev updates the template. The functional test is not about style. So this change should pass test without changing test. You're proposing (what symfony docs are proposing too) is to tie your test template implementation.

Comment: If you want to test a route, so fr example if `GET /acme/demo` is resolved correctly, you can just create a client, send the request and then get the response from the client as described in the documentation. From the request you can assert the status code (200), if required headers are present and more: https://symfony.com/doc/current/testing.html#index-3 All of this does not rely on the html output.

Comment: If you want to do functional testing on a lower level, you could use your config_test.yml to replace production services with stubs or sandbox services and then use the kernel to test all kind of things, including your controller and the response it will return given certain request input. Discussing this would require a more concrete example.

Comment: @dbrumann yes, but I need to verify that variables passed to template are there, instead verifying it in html content.

check update of the question where I've posted video link.

How can this be done:
"you could use your config_test.yml to replace production services with stubs or sandbox services and then use the kernel to test all kind of things"

Comment: Your controller should not be responsible for finding the value "59,00" that should be done in your service layer. So you should have something like a PriceCaclulator service and test that. If you test it in the controller, but before the template is rendered, then you will have overhead and slow tests and at the same time you won't have the benefit it offers, that it will test end to end. You could write a test where you assert that your controller gives the right values to the template engine as well, but you might as well test the actual service that provides the data. It's easier & faster.

Comment: Please see the video (not all the way to end, just few min) and you'll see the idea.

Comment: If you write a test over the full request-response-cycle you want to ensure that the final result is what you expected, including that prices are rendered correctly. If your template changes how it looks, than the test is expected to break, because most of the times in an ecommerce project this should only be done intentionally and therefore requires you to change the specification in other words, update the tests.

Comment: Can you outline the code in your question which code you wrote to get the original request data in a test despite it did not work? This could greatly improve your question.